# How can I display pretty-print YAML in my angular2 app?

Tags: angular, yaml

I am needing to display pretty-print YAML content in my Angular2 app. What is the best/most simple way to do this? I know there is a json pipe. Does anyone have an example of a yaml pipe?

Like this image where it's parsed and color-coded.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use html element `<pre>{YOUR_YAML_CODE}</pre>`

Comment: Not that simple. They want things to be pretty-print. I'll add an image.